# Returning other page after upload image in mvc3 using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am using 2 models for one view ,one model is showing in form and other one is also using form but it is showing in a div tag so after uploading image the pop up is closing but i need to show the pop up with the data?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is implemented? It's not clear what you are doing. Maybe add some code or describe the HTML involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply returning another page can be accomplished by returning a `RedirectResult` from your action method:

```
return Redirect("url");
```

If that's not what you're looking for, then you'll need to be a bit more specific with your question, as it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.